# Parallax Effect on single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I don't really think parallax is the best word to describe what I'm trying to achieve but I don't know how to word it otherwise.

Basically, I have a header section that is fixed that allows the rest of the page to slide over top it and that works as expected.

However, I'd like to have another section similar to that in the middle.

Order of events I'm trying to achieve:

1. -User at top of page, header fully visible full height
2. -User scrolls down, content of page slides over top of header
3. -Once user has LAYER A near top of page, make this layer stay at fixed position
4. -User continues to scroll down page, LAYER B(rest of page) continues to slide over LAYER A(perhaps leaving just 75px or so of the div
   visible)

I've also created an image to go along with this[image]

I've tried using fixed relative positioning using transform but that wasn't exactly working. Ideally I'd like to use pure CSS to achieve this but I'm not against using jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT 2: I've achieved my effect...may have bene overthinking it. It's sorty hacky and I'm  sure there are better ways to handle it, but I've done this with:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($(".nav_bar").offset().top > 1057) {
    $(".fixedsection_wrapper").addClass("fixedposition"); }
else {
    $(".fixedsection_wrapper").removeClass("fixedposition");
}
});
```

All that does is place position:fixed on the the "Layer A" when it comes in contact with the nav bar. It then behaves as the diagram depicts.

Comment: Can you post HTML/CSS for the header section?

Comment: @abmitchell, This is the code below for ONLY the header section, let me know if you need the rest as well.

Comment: Actually, added it to the top post

Answer (score 0):

There are many parallax scripts out there that I've used for various projects. It takes me a long time to get them work the way I want them to, so its best to experiment with either your script, or someone else's.

Usually, they look at the parent, and then the code makes it so that the space between the parent and the 2 child div layers change distance.

For example:

Parent A holds Children B, C, D.
You want the Parallax to happen on "C".
Distance between B and D need to change to simulate that effect usually by translating the background-image of C upwards as you scroll, and then changing the distance between B and D as you scroll. D will change the distance faster than B will change distance, and C will translate at a near 1:2 ratio as you scroll up.

To sum it up, using a parallax script, most tend to follow that format. My solution to your problem is that you nest your Parallax inside a wrapper, and then surround it by 2 other div's with content. I might be over simplifying your issue, but that's how I solved my issue.

Comment: Something I feel I should add, which is more so causing my problems. I believe I could make this effect work in pure CSS if I was just changing background images. In your example, Child "C" would be the orange in my picture at the top. In this DIV is a sliding carousel which uses position:relative and such inside.

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking this though. Wonder if I can set the background per slide as fixed and and achieve it this way.

Comment: With so many ways to do things, the easiest way is to crunch code in there and wait until you start seeing things work. In your case, I can spend all day and night showing you examples of code to get it to work for you, but in your scenario, its what you feel is the best and most achievable method of getting the job done.

Comment: So if you happen to see this:

Still haven't achieved the effect I'm looking for, but I'm starting to think it may be best to adjust the height based on scroll position.

As in detect if my fixed nav at the top is say, 500 pixels down the page where this effect is supposed to take place then begin reducing height as the user continues to scroll. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: No, if that works, thats great! From my knowledge, CSS based fixed navbars are always at 0px from the top, and therefore have no positional data you can pull. I suggest using a jquery sticky script and then use a script that makes anchors at any point you want on that page. I suggest using these two scripts to achieve your results:
http://stickyjs.com/
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Hmm..so would I use the window scroll(or nav position) in an if statement, like if nav is > 800px, make my carousel/parallax div sticky at top then reduce height(with overflow:hidden) as the user scrolls?

Comment: Kinda confused how to achieve the second part. I've seen some examples but most deal with full page background stuff.

Comment: I edited my top post...not sure if that's the worst possible way to do it or not but it seems to be working.

Comment: `function paraEffect(navbar, fixedwrap, fixedpos, distance) {
 $(window).scroll(function() {

 if ($(navbar).offset().top > distance) {
  $(fixedwrap).addClass(fixedpos); }
 else {
  $(fixedwrap).removeClass(fixedpos);
 }
 });
 
}`

This is a passive function you can use to modulate your code. I'm sure you could have done it yourself, but if you want to every do more than one at a time (assuming you can), then this should work.

Comment: excellent! I'm considering doing another one of these lower in the body as well, I'm really liking the effect.

Thanks again :)